# Rust: serialization and deserialization of fixed-size slice

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to serialize and deserialize using serde a following struct:

```
const COUNT: usize = 4096;

struct MyStruct {
    a: [u16; COUNT],
    b: [u8: COUNT]
}
```

So, the basic idea is that I have quite large (more than implemented fixed-length array traits in serde) fixed-length arrays inside of it. Because of that serde doesn't know how to serialize and deserialize `[T; 4096]` (despite the fact it knows how to handle `u8` and `u16`).

I guess I have to write my own implementations of `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits for `MyStruct`, but I don't quite understand how to do that. If I use `serialize_struct` in my trait I have to call `serialize_field` that also doesn't know how to work with `[T; 4096]`.

Of course I don't want to convert fixed-length slices to vectors, perform any copy operations and I would like to not store length of such arrays explicilty in non self-describing formats (e. g. postcard), because `COUNT` is not going to change.

Comment: Not related to the question, but size of `MyStruct` is `12 KiB`. It is quite a lot. Maybe you should consider storing it and/or it's contents on the heap.

Comment: I've added an up-to-date answer on the linked question. That looks like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d02fb5c26832f78a3c3c5cdc595fa1eb) for your case (playground won't compile due to no `serde_with`). The length is not stored since it's serialized as a tuple.